# boost signal with min_element

Tags: c++, boost

I am writing a little example to try to understand multiple return values of boost::signal. However, the result seems weired to me.

```
#include <boost/signal.hpp> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm> 

int func1() 
{ 
    return 3; 
} 

int func2() 
{ 
    return 4; 
} 

int func3()
{
    return 2;
}

template <typename T> 
struct min_element 
{ 
    typedef T result_type;  //result_type is required by boost::signal

    template <typename InputIterator> 
    T operator()(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) const 
    {
        std::cout<<*std::min_element(first, last)<<std::endl;  //I got 3 here
        return T(first, last); 
    } 
}; 

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    boost::signal<int (), min_element<std::vector<int> > > s; 
    s.connect(func1); 
    s.connect(func2); 
    s.connect(func3);
    std::vector<int> v = s();
    std::cout<<*std::min_element(v.begin(),v.end())<<std::endl; //I got 2 here
    return 0;
}
```

The first min_element would output "3" while the second would output "2". Obviously "2" is the smallest number among those three. I don't know what's wrong with the first one. In operator() I also tried to iterate from first to last and I got the sequence "3,4,2" which seems correct. But why would min_element give me "3" instead?

The code was compiled with VS2010 SP1. The version of Boost is 1.46.1 which is the latest one.

Thanks in advance.

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird. Replacing `operator()`:

```
T operator()(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) const 
{
    InputIterator result = first;

    while (++first != last) {
//      *result;
        std::cout<<*first<<std::endl;
    }

    return T();
}
```

Works, but as soon as you dereference `result`, `first` and `result` both get stuck at 3. This is what `std::min_element` is doing; I found my implementation's source and stripped it down to what you've seen above.

I have no idea what's going on.

This is Boost 1.38.0 on GCC 4.5.0.